# Invalid factor level in loop to `strsplit` data

Tags: r

Example data:

```
tmp <-
c("30.55,114.27", "39.31,115.92", "0,0", "0,0", "27.35,111.78", 
"0,0", "34.47,118.97", "34.62,113.72", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "31.43,120.55", 
"0,0", "0,0", "31.67,119.82", "44.28,129.04", "23.37,113.44", 
"23.31,112.84", "24.41,102.34", "30.77,104.24", "0,0")
```

Loop to string split data:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(as.character(NA),as.character(NA))
for(i in 1:length(tmp)){#nrow(train2)){
  dat1[i,] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp[i], ","))  
}
```

Problem:

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>
> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "29.29") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "106.25") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "0") :
> ```

However if I run it for just 1 row it looks right:

```
> do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp[i], ","))  
     [,1]    [,2]    
[1,] "30.55" "114.27"
```

Comment: Look at `str(dat1)` before the `for` loop, and the warning message will probably make more sense.

Comment: ...maybe you'd prefer something more like `do.call(rbind,lapply(tmp,function(x) strsplit(x,",")[[1]]))`?

Comment: Regarding the first comment I see your point. Though I could swear I got the same error when I set up `dat1` with numerics. Let me try the code in your 2nd comment. Just 1 sec.

Comment: Is the loop really necessary? How about `dat1 <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(tmp,","))`?

Comment: @RHertel Yeah, I think you're right.

Comment: @RHertel and @ joran Awesome, yes that worked (the one without the loop). Thank you as well joran. Using the code from the 2nd comment without fixing `dat1` still gave the same warning/error but if I fixed `dat1` first it probably would've worked. It's way faster without that loop tho :) If one of you wants to make that into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Note : `do.call(...)` will return a `matrix`. If you need a `data.frame`, please make necessary conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a loop is not needed in this case. You could try

```
dat1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp, ","))
```